# Trying to find the proper way but I couldn't

Tags: javascript, html

- User has 1000 INR when he starts the game
- Every try(click on start) is charged 100 INR
- Game is over if user has less than 100 INR
- Every try generates three random numbers, each random number is in 0-9 range
- If all the numbers are odd/even (eg. 2 4 6), user gets 300 INR
- If the numbers are in sequence with difference of 1 in any order (eg. 2 3 4 or 3 2 4 or 4 6 5), user gets 800 INR
- If all the numbers are same (eg. 4 4 4), user gets 1000 INR
- Else user gets no money

  ```
  function randomNum(min, max) {
    var YourMoney = 100
    var MoneyLeft
    var n = []
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      n.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min)
    }
    document.getElementById("randomNumbers").innerHTML = n;

    YourMoney = YourMoney - 100
    document.getElementById("remain").innerHTML = YourMoney

    if (YourMoney < 100) {
      document.getElementById("lost").innerHTML = "You have lost ";
    }

  }
  ```

Comment: Where’s the code that calls this function? What specific problem are you having? You’ve defined how your game should work, but you haven’t actually described a problem or asked a question.

Comment: hello, Adam..kindly check my snippet..it meets your all requirements!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written this code in 1 hr! phew! :)..hope it helps..also remove all console when you understand full code!

```js
var points = 1000;
 document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = points
function randomNum() {
 // var YourMoney = 100
  //var MoneyLeft
  if(points.toString() == "100"){
   alert("you have lost!");
  }else{
  points = points-100;
   document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = points

  var n = []
  var number = 0;
var digits = '';

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    digits = digits + number.toString();
}
console.log("digits--",digits)
  document.getElementById("randomNumbers").innerHTML = digits;
let x = String(digits).split('')
console.log("x--",x)
// for(var i =0; i<x.length; i++){
// if(Math.abs(i % 2) == 1){
// console.log("no is odd");
// }
// })
// if( i % 2 == 0){
// console.log("no is even");
// }
// }
var result = [];
for(var i =0; i<x.length; i++){
console.log("Math.abs(i % 2)--",Math.abs(i % 2))
if(Math.abs(x[i] % 2) == 1){
console.log("no is odd");
result.push('odd');
}else if(Math.abs(x[i] % 2) == 0){
console.log("no is even");
result.push('even');
}
}

var matches = [""]; digits.split("").forEach(function(val){ 
  var lastNum = 0;
  if ( matches[matches.length-1].length > 0 )
  {
    lastNum = parseInt(matches[matches.length-1].slice(-1),10);
  }
  var currentNum = parseInt(val,10);
  if ( currentNum == lastNum + 1 ) 
  { 
    matches[matches.length-1] += String(currentNum); 
  }
  else 
  { 
    if ( matches[matches.length-1].length > 1 ) 
    { 
       matches.push(String(currentNum)) 
    } 
    else 
    { matches[matches.length-1] = String(currentNum); 
    } 
  }
});
matches = matches.filter(function(val){ return val.length > 1 }) //outputs ["6789", "123"]
console.log("matchg",matches.length);
//document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(matches,0,4);
console.log("arrarrarr",result,"--",result.every( (val, i, arr) => val === arr[0] ));
if(result.every( (val, i, arr) => val === arr[0] )){
//same values
points = points+300;
alert("congratulation you have won "+300+ "points")
   document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = points
 
}else if(matches.length == 3){
//sequence
points = points+800;
alert("congratulation you have won "+800+ "points")
   document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = points

}else if (x.every( (val, i, arr) => val === arr[0] )){
//all values are same
points = points+1000;
alert("congratulation you have won "+1000+ "points")
   document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = points
}else{
alert("better luck next time!");
}
  }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Your points:<b id="points"></b></div>
<button onclick="randomNum()">START</button><div>Your Lucky no: <b id="randomNumbers"></b></div>
```